# how to copy data from pdf and paste it into excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel, copy

i have tried this code but it is not working properly kindly help me with this.

```
Sub Shell_Copy_Paste()

   Dim o As Variant
   Dim wkSheet As Worksheet

   Set wkSheet = ActiveSheet

   o = Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe C:\Users\saurabh.ad.sharma\Desktop\red.pdf", vbNormalFocus)

   Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)) 'Wait for Acrobat to load

   SendKeys "^a"   'Select All
   SendKeys "^c"   'Copy
   SendKeys "%{F4}"    'Close shell application

   wkSheet.Range("B5").Select
   SendKeys "^v"   'Paste

End Sub
```

kindly point out the error and me with this

Comment: It would be easier for everyone if **you** point out the error, and then let us help you to fix it.  Which line does it crash on?  What error message do you get?  If it doesn't crash, what is it not doing that you think it should be doing?

Comment: In principle the code works (just tested it), but there are so many things that can fail (Reader doesn't start, PDF-File cannot be opened, PDF contains only an image to name only a few) that you really should tell what exactly your problem is - and what you already did by yourself to find the problem

Comment: it is copying the file from pdf by copying it but actually not pasting it to the excel

Comment: pdf is having a table with two columns name and phone no. it is copying it but pasting not it in excel

Comment: And after copying, you can paste it into excel manually?

Comment: yes i can but i want to automate it

Comment: plus two column are coming in same cell... and it is not  matching the exact table format of the pdf

Comment: Try the Paste-Command with `wkSheet.Paste` rather than `SendKeys "^v"`. However, it will paste what is copied from the PDF - it's not an Excel issue if the `copy`-Part doesn't copy the data as you expect. Maybe you have to write some code to divide the data into 2 columns

Comment: ohk thank u so much thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best if you don't hard code your macros. The below code will allow you to select the file you want, so you wont have problem with opening the PDF file.

```
Sub run()


Dim fn As String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
.AllowMultiSelect = False
If .Show = -1 Then
fn = .SelectedItems(1)
Else
MsgBox "You cancel the process."
Exit Sub
End If
End With

End Sub
```